# Getting std::bad_alloc when trying to open image with exiv2

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, exiv2

Hello I'm trying to read metadata from image using exiv2, but when opening the file I get the following error: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc

I'm using default c++ visual studio 2019 compiler.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include "exiv2/exiv2.hpp"

inline bool file_exists(const std::string& name) {
    struct stat buffer;
    return (stat(name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        Exiv2::XmpParser::initialize();
        ::atexit(Exiv2::XmpParser::terminate);
#ifdef EXV_ENABLE_BMFF
        Exiv2::enableBMFF();
#endif

        const char* file = "E:/img/DJI_0001.jpg";
        if (!file_exists(file)) return 0;
        Exiv2::Image::AutoPtr image = Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(file);
        assert(image.get() != 0);
        image->readMetadata();
    }
    catch (Exiv2::Error& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught Exiv2 exception '" << e.what() << "'\n";
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: your  `file_exists` function looks highly suspicious. what is this supposed to be?

Comment: At first I thought maybe the file couldn't be found so I made a function to check if file exists, the function doesn't give any errors tho.

Comment: what is `stat`?

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/stat.html

Comment: Basically checks the status of the file, by using that you can check if this file exists.

Comment: Shouldn't the path to file passed to the `Exiv2::ImageFactory::open` begin with the `file://` prefix?

Comment: Changed the file string to: "file://E:/img/DJI_0001.jpg", still the same.

Comment: Why use `stat`? C++ has `std::ifstream` which can be used to check if the file exists or not.

Comment: References: https://www.exiv2.org/doc/classExiv2_1_1ImageFactory.html#aba929c4ca4a71625d12bcb97bcc28161

Comment: A Windows file URI has an added slash in front of the drive letter; try `"file:///E:/img/DJI_0001.jpg"`. (Leaving it out will make `ImageFactory` look for `"/img/DJI_0001.jpg"`, which might work – but just by accident – only if your working directory and the file are on the same drive.)

Comment: Did you ever figure the problem out? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to an ABI incompatibility between your C++ standard library version and the one exiv2 was compiled with. I suppose you are using a pre-built exiv2 library?

You can check this by calling `Exiv2::versionNumber()` vs `Exiv2::versionString()`. The former will work but the latter probably crash because of the `std::string` involved.

**Solution:** Do not use the pre-compiled version of exiv2 but compile it yourself within the same dev environment of your main project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the open method.
I followed the instructions of matthias and build the lib myself.
First the error remained. I then created specific versions for Debug and Release and used the appropriate version for my program.
This fixed the issue on my side.

Edit: I also tried the pre-compiled version with my release build. That was also working well.

Comment: why not just edit or comment on matthias' answer?

Comment: thanks for the hint, david... Is that still possible once an answer was already posted?

Comment: yes it should be

Comment: Thanks for your comments on this. But I have not enough reputation to comment on matthias answer. Maybe my answer helps someone else anyway...

Comment: just another thought: If you vote my answer up, my reputation is above 50. Then I could delete this answer and comment on Matthias. What do you think?